# Find a sentence is related to a medical term or not

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning

Input: user enters a sentence

if the word is related to any medical term , or if he needs any medical attention,

Output=True

else
Output=False

I am reading https://www.nltk.org/. I scraped 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/medical/a' this website to get the medical related words but I am unable to figure out how to detect the sentence which are related to medical term . I haven't done any code because the algorithm is not clear to me.

I want to know what should I use , where to start, I need a tutorial link to implement this thing. Any guidance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will list down the various ways you can do this with naive to intelligent ways -

1. Get a large vocabulary of medical terms, iterate over the sentence and return yes or no incase you find anything
2. Get a large vocabulary of medical terms, iterate over the sentence and do a fuzzy match with each word, so that words that are variations of the same work syntactically (alphabetically) are still detected and caught. [Check fuzzywuzzy library in python]
3. Get a large vocabulary of medical terms with definitions for each. Use pre-trained word embeddings (word2vec, Glove etc) for each word in the descriptions of those terms. Take a weighted sum of each word embeddings with weights set to the TFIDF of each word, to represent each medical term (its description to be precise) as a vector. Repeat the process for the sentence as well. Then take a cosine similary between them to calculate how contextually similar is the text to the description of the medical term. If the similarity is above a certain threshold that you fix, then return True. [This approach doesnt need the exact term, even if the person is talking about the condition, it should be able to detect]
4. Label a large number of sentences with their respective medical terms in them (annotate using something like the API.AI entity annotation tool or RASA entity annotation tool). Create a neural network with input embedding layer (which you can initialise with word2vec embeddings if you like), bi-LSTM layers and output with the list of medical terms / conditions with softmax. This will get you probability of each condition or term being associated with the sentence.
5. Create a neural network with encoder decoder architecture with attention layer between them. Create encoder embeddings from the input sentence. Create decoder with output as a string of medical terms. Train an encoder-decoder attention layer with pre-annotated data.
6. Create a pointer network which as input takes a sentence with the respective medical terms and return pointers, which point back to the inputs and marks them as medical term or non-medical term. (not easy to build fyi...)

Answer (score 0):

OK so, I don't understand which part do you not understand? Because, the idea is rather simple and one google search gives you great and easy results. Unless the issue is that you don't know python. In that case it will be very hard for you to implement this.

The idea itself is simple - tokenize sentence (have each word for itself in a list) and search the list of medical terms. If the current word is in the list, the term is medical so the sentence is related to that medical term as well. If you imagine that you have a list of medical terms in a `medical_terms` list then in python it would look something like this:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthurs' abdomen was hurting."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthurs', 'abdomen', "was", 'hurting', '.']
>>> def is_medical(tokens):
...   for i in tokens:
...     if i in medical_terms:
...       return True
...     else:
...       return False 

>>> is_medical(tokens)
True
```

You just tokenize the input sentence with NLTK and then search the list if any of the words in the sentence are medical terms. You can adapt this function to work with [n-grams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) as well. This has a lot of other approaches and different special cases that have to be handled by this is the good start.

Comment: I have a very large numbers of medical terms as I scraped the whole Doctor's dictionary. as per your solution this  is_medical function will compare my string with a huge lengthed list called ' medical_terms ' . I am trying to avoid this huge comparison. Is there any way? like I train a model and each time I input something ,the trained model will give the results. I am new to this kind of work. so I am not sure how the model works. But I want my result in minimal time

Comment: The model can definitely capture broader context and give better results, but that would be too complicated for this task for now. You can divide medical terms in a dictionary with first two letters of a word as a key and a list of medical terms that start with those two letters as a value of a dictionary. That would significantly reduce the search time.

Comment: ok. I can see 'Notify' word is present in doctor's dictionary. if i write like this, 'I will notify you when he calls me' . It is not a medical related sentence. but it will still show as medical word. how can i avoid this??

Comment: Well, you can go through the data and discard words like that. But then again it would take too much time. But the problem is that any model, no matter how sophisticated, is only as good as the data you’re training it on. So, if you find some dataset with sentences of patients talking to doctor then you can try doing this task with LSTMs but otherwise, this is not worth doing this way...